# Add "rate my app" action to a button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to implement a button that makes the action of rating my app, only when touching that button. It's just a simple action.

I guess its just an alert view, but I really don't know how to start it. I never implemented one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Vergmort as par waf suggest its very easy and nice use of **APPirater**. is show rating alert as u wish day's and timing wise like this:-

[image]

you just implements just some easy step:-

- Download code from this link:- https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater
- Only this Three File Are Require your Project:-

  `AppiraterDelegate.h`
  `Appirater.h`
  `Appirater.m`
- Add this Three File in to your Project and import this `#import "Appirater.h"` where you want to show this rate alert.
- puth this pies of code:-(also mantion in https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater how to impliment)

  ```
      [Appirater setAppId:@"111111111"];         //yourApp id
      [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
      [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5];
      [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:1];
      [Appirater setDebug:YES];             //please while you upload app please setDebug `YES` to `NO` becouse its only for developer testing .
      [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
  ```

Hope you got your solution by my full of description. enjoy coding :)

**EDIT**

You can appear this using Button click action like Bellow :-

for example your Button action in to **exampleviewcontroller.m** then you need to import `#import "Appirater.h"` in **exampleviewcontroller.m** then.

```
-(IBAction)yourBtnAction
{
            [Appirater setAppId:@"111111111"];         //yourApp id
            [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
            [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5];
            [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:1];
            [Appirater setDebug:YES];             //please while you upload app please setDebug `YES` to `NO` becouse its only for developer testing .
            [Appirater appLaunched:YES];

}
```

Comment: Hi @NitinGohel good explanation. Can I ask you a question? Can I make this alert to appear only when clicking a button?

Answer (score 3):

Like many have pointed out it has been answered, but you should also look at APPirater. This is a great drop in solution to automate this for you.

https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

Comment: can u help me implement this?

Comment: Sure. Download the file from the link, follow the instructions on the front page of the link as well (scroll to the bottom). Pm if you have more questions AFTER doing that